# How to add cursor to text field on page load?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an attendance site in Drupal 7 and I use a reference entity field to accept scanned ID badges. Once the ID number is saved in the field the page reloads.

I'd like to have a cursor appear in the field after the page is reloaded. I know this can be done with java script but I haven't been able to get it to work. I added `scripts[] = scripts.js` in the `.info` of the theme and created a `.js` file with the same name in my theme directory.

```
(function setFocus() {
document.getElementById("field_student").focus();
```

}

```
function select() {
    document.getElementById("field_student").select();
```

}

I'm not very adept at javascript and I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: To me it looks right. Does the input tag really has the id "field_student". Maybe you chose the id of a wrapping div or the real id is something else, maybe "field-student"?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do it with html autofocus now - no need for JS.

You should be able to do it with this:

```
<?php
  // inside a hook_form_alter()      

  $form['field'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes' => array('autofocus' => TRUE)),
  ];
```

Comment: That's great, do place this in  style.css?

Comment: This is PHP code...

Comment: Nope. You have to add that in your module / template code.